# UnityContainer.BuildUp() - Can I make it inject new instances into properties only if these are null?

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container, property-injection

I'm deserializing a class like this one

```
class AClass{
    [Dependency]
    AnotherClass Property{ get; set; }
}
```

When I then BuildUp() the object I'd like Unity to create a new instance of AnotherClass only if the property is null and otherwise just perform a BuildUp on it.
Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Edit: I'm doing mvvm with wpf. The classes are view-models, I serialize them as there are some properties I want to preserve between runs and they also have some dependencies I want unity to inject. So after deserialization the nested model is already there with properties set so I don't want unity to override it with a new instance but I still want it to call InjectionMethods on it and also to resolve it normally the first time the program is run and the nested models are null.

Comment: Can you be a bit more concrete? What is the reason for that property to be already set?

Comment: @Steven I hope that now it is a bit clearer what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up writing a unity extension. 
I could not find much documentation on how to do this so I'm not really sure about the result.
It seems to work but I have this feeling I might have written something horrible..
Anyway here's the code, improvements are welcome:

```
public class RecursiveBuildUpContainerExtension : UnityContainerExtension {
        protected override void Initialize(){
            Context.Strategies.Add( new RecursiveBuildUpBuilderStrategy( Context.Container ), UnityBuildStage.PreCreation );
        }
    }

    public class RecursiveBuildUpBuilderStrategy : BuilderStrategy {
        readonly IUnityContainer container;
        public RecursiveBuildUpBuilderStrategy( IUnityContainer container ) {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public override void PreBuildUp( IBuilderContext context ) {

            if( context.Existing == null ) return;

            foreach( var prop in context.Existing.GetType( ).GetProperties( ) ) {

                if( ContainsType<DependencyAttribute>( prop.GetCustomAttributes( true ) ) ) {

                    if( prop.GetValue( context.Existing, null ) == null ) {
                        var value = container.Resolve( prop.PropertyType );
                        prop.GetSetMethod( ).Invoke( context.Existing, new[] { value } );
                    }
                    else {
                        var value = container.BuildUp( prop.PropertyType, prop.GetValue( context.Existing, null ) );
                        prop.GetSetMethod( ).Invoke( context.Existing, new[] { value } );
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var method in context.Existing.GetType().GetMethods() ){
                if( ContainsType<InjectionMethodAttribute>( method.GetCustomAttributes( true ))){
                    var argsInfo = method.GetParameters( );
                    var args = new object[argsInfo.Length];

                    for( int i = 0; i < argsInfo.Length; i++ ) {
                        args[i] = container.Resolve( argsInfo[i].ParameterType );
                    }

                    method.Invoke( context.Existing, args );
                }
            }

            context.BuildComplete = true;
        }

        private static bool ContainsType<T>( IEnumerable<object> objects ){
            foreach (var o in objects){
                if( o is T ) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really, really helpful. See here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728663/using-unitys-dependency-injection-in-data-annotations?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own `BuildUp` method, like this:

```cs
public static void BuildUpButSkipInitializedProperties(
    this UnityContainer container, object instance)
{
    var registeredTypes = (
        from registration in container.Registrations
        select registration.RegisteredType)
        .ToArray();

    var injectableProperties =
        from property in instance.GetType().GetProperties()
        where property.GetGetMethod() != null
        where property.GetSetMethod() != null
        where property.GetValue(instance, null) == null
        where registeredTypes.Contains(property.PropertyType)
        select property;

    foreach (var property in injectableProperties)
    {
        object value = container.Resolve(property.PropertyType);
        property.SetValue(instance, value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var instance = new AClass();

container.BuildUpButSkipInitializedProperties(instance);
```

I didn't test or even compile this code, but it should pretty much do the trick. Note that since it iterates all `Registrations` every time and injects all properties using reflection, it might not be the fasted thing ;-)

Comment: This isn't so bad but it won't work if there are more than two levels of nested objects.. I know this wasn't in my original question so thank you anyway for your answer! you have my +1.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a simple way? No.

You'd need to edit the generated il, detect already existing objects... It could be done but it's in no way simple.

Comment: hmm.. I'm not sure why I would need to edit il.. what il btw that of my class??

Comment: The container itself generates IL dynamically to create the functions that create & resolve objects. It's complex but a massive perfect win. To get the behavior you want you'd need to generate different IL. Or fall back to reflection. In either case it's pretty low level hacking on the container itself.

Comment: Are there any resources on how this works? I had a hard time finding anything.. I know I can read the source, but an explanation would be better :)